antd modal component is not showing in Blazor
I'm creating a modal component with antD to display some info, this component is nested in a parent component where i'm passing a value through a parameter called Visible, the first time the page renders i can open the modal but for some reason after closing the modal when clicking the button to show it again it doesn´t show, it seems that it's a problem with reactiveness of blazor or something like that but i don't really understand whats wrong with it
(parent component )
@using gluenet.Components.Pages.SensitivityAnalisysComponents
@code{

     private bool flowingVisible = false;

     void OpenFlowingGradient()
     {
       flowingVisible = true;
        
     }

}

<Button Icon="@IconType.Outline.Plus" OnClick="()=>OpenFlowingGradient()"/>

<FlowingGradientSurvey Visible="flowingVisible"/>

(child component) #inside of the folder SensitivityAnalisysComponents
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}

<Modal
    @bind-Visible="@Visible" 
    OkText="@("Apply")"
    CancelText="@("Cancel")" 
    Centered="true" 
    MaxBodyHeight="@("80vh")" 
    style="width: 70vw;">

    Here i put the content that i want to show...

</Modal>

If someone can explain please why i'm getting this behavior it would be really helpful, because I don't simply understand

You could try following to implement chain bind @bind-Visible="flowingVisible":
FlowingGradientSurvey.razor
@using AntDesign
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> VisibleChanged { get; set; }
}
<Modal @bind-Visible="@Visible">
    Here i put the content that i want to show...
</Modal>

parent
...
<FlowingGradientSurvey @bind-Visible="flowingVisible" />
...

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#binding-with-component-parameters

You need to build two way binding into your child component.  Here's my refactored component.  Note I've bound the getter to the pass thro value and the setter to the EventCallback.

<Modal style="width: 70vw;"
       @bind-Visible:get="Visible"
       @bind-Visible:set="OnVisibleChanged"
       OkText="@("Apply")"
       CancelText="@("Cancel")"
       Centered="true"
        
       MaxBodyHeight="@("80vh")">

    Here i put the content that i want to show...

</Modal>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Visible { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> VisibleChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnVisibleChanged(bool value)
    {
        await this.VisibleChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}

Your page then looks like this.  I've added the two way binding to the component.
@page "/"

<PageContainer Title="Welcome">

    <Button Icon="@IconType.Outline.Plus" OnClick="OpenFlowingGradient" />

    <MyComponent @bind-Visible="_flowingVisible" />

</PageContainer>

@code {
    private bool _flowingVisible = false;

    private Task OpenFlowingGradient()
    {
        _flowingVisible = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0 - for a more detailed explanation.
